# Installing two different xampp versions in different directories

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ssl, xampp

I tried installing two different xampp versions in E:\xampp_ows (xampp 1.8) first and then in C:\xampp (xampp 5.6) following the tutorial from [here](http://webdevzoom.com/install-run-multiple-xampp-windows/). 
Now, when I try running the apache and mysql services from E:\xampp_ows it works fine but when I try to run services from C:\xampp it says 'Attempting to start Apache service' And it does start apache but from E:\xampp_ows and serves E:\xampp_ows\htdocs directory, same problem with MySQL service. 
P.S. I have changed the main port and ssl port to 8080 and 4433 respectively in httpd.conf, httpd-ssl.conf and in main config->service and port settings. 
How can I avoid this issue? Thanks

Comment: why do you need 2 xmapp servers in the first placE?

Comment: See comments part in the same url from where you are trying .. there are some more issues users faced and came up with solution there.

Comment: did you run "setup_xampp.bat" in xampp folder? most of the time this fixes the problems.

Comment: @madalinivascu 2 servers because i need to run two different php versions mainly the updated version.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave tried almost all of them, no issue regarding this.

Comment: I guess you can install multiple php versions in the single xampp install. https://superuser.com/questions/123902/getting-xampp-to-work-with-multiple-version-of-php

Comment: @AminAdel yes i ran setup_xampp.bat from C:\xampp it says nothing to update, (I have also checked xampp-control.ini file the ports are already updated.

Comment: try using the portable versions and make sure you aren't running both at the same time

Comment: check windows system environment path and make sure both php versions in both xampps exist there.

Comment: updating the php version sounds a good alternative. I ll try the portable version too later. **Thanks** everyone.

Comment: @OWS Please dont forget to post your solution as answer after you come up with something and how you achieved. It will help future readers. Thanks